# ReactJS Meterial UI Autocomplete, Show focus state of component by default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

[Material UI autocomplete](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/auto-complete) component have nice style while the input field is focused. (you can find it on the linked page)

Is it possible to make this focus state default? Meaning when the component is loaded this is the state it will be on, no matter if I am focusing on the element or clicking away from it.

### Current Default

[image: Current default]

### Expected Default

[image: Expected Default]

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the prop "autoFocus". It works for me at v.0.19.x

Answer (score 0):

Its dead simple. Use floatingLabelFixed props and set it to true.

```
floatingLabelFixed={true}
```